# How can I add one element of array to all elements of another array using foreach loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

How can I add one element of array with every element of another array using foreach loop in php?

For clear understanding attaching screen shot.
[image]
in this picture element at index one will be add to all elements of another array. then element at index two will be add to every element of another array and so on...

Comment: Shaiz have you tried my answer?

Comment: @shaiz review again my answer probably it may resolve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please review below code.

```
<?php
$arr = array(11,12,13,14,15);
$arrAnotherArray = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
$subArrLen = count($arrAnotherArray);

foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    $arr[$key] = array();    
    $sum = 0;
   foreach($arrAnotherArray as $key1=>$val){    
         $sum = $value + $val;
         array_push($arr[$key],$sum);
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: I try both of the methods but it doesn't give me my required result.

Comment: @Shaiz I did code based on your expected result. so please elaborate your requirement properly.

Comment: @Shaiz I update an answer please take followup whether it's resolve your issue or not

Comment: Dipak chavda Sir, thanks for support. i want this in foreach loop and i want to sum one element of one array with every element of another array...thank u sir.

Comment: @shaiz Hope so this may a qualified answer please review logic again

Comment: Sir thank u so very much.. perfect answer.. yes this was my question and its a correct code.. thank u so mch sir... bunch of thanks sir Dipak Chavda and Ketan Solanki...so nice of u

Comment: @shaiz Please try to post your question properly so we know your purpose easily and give you an answer quickly and perfect

Comment: @shaiz this is thumbs up for you

Comment: Sorry sir i bother both of you to much. next time i ll be very carefull.sir thumbs up for both u. you guys help me alot.

Comment: oH sorry sir. i have marked  :) .. i forget to mark.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this :

```
$mainArray = array("11","12","13"....);
$returnArray = array();

foreach($mainArray as $key => $value){
    $subArray = array();
    //Create the sub array here as you want it.
    $subArray[] = $key + 1;
    $subArray[] = $key + 2;
    $subArray[] = $key + 3;
    $subArray[] = $key + 4;
    $subArray[] = $key + 5;
    $subArray[] = $key + 6;

    $returnArray[$value] = $subArray;
}
```

Comment: How can I add one element of array to all elements of another array using foreach loop in php, suppose $mainArray[0] we pick. now i want to add it with each element of $subArray elements like this,,, $mainArray[0]+$subArray[0],   $mainArray[0]+$subArray[1], $mainArray[0]+$subArray[2],then it will move to the next index of main array and will add with every element of another array. hope so you get my point what i want  :)

Comment: your answer is write, you are appending elements but i want to sum the elements . like 11+1, 11+2,

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you want your output to be formatted but here's the addition logic...

```
$main = range(11,14);
$sub = range(1,6);

$output = [];


foreach ($main as $mainNumber) {
    foreach ($sub as $subNumber) {
        $output[$mainNumber . '+' . $subNumber] = $mainNumber + $subNumber;
    }
}

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: thanks i got correct output by Dipak chavda provided logic.